# How to send message (card and notification) to Teams Bot from my API?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

How to send message (card and notification, and any different actions) to my Teams Bot from my API (Stand-alone application)?

I can send "Activity" to chat using
`connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync(conversationId, messageActivity)`; But it's just a message and my Bot doesn't "hear" the message.

I need to **send notification or card** to specific conversation (specific user that installed my Teams APP and loged in to our service). I use "OAuthPrompt" for authorizing.
Then ... The card should be displayed in chat and user can react on it or ignore.

Card should be interractive and identified by object Id (I need to send the data to Stand-alone application back by object Id if user adds a note)...
Something like the following

PS.: As I wrote ... I send "Activity" using SendToConversationAsync ...Do you know how to handle/catch the message on bot side?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @imfantom,

Could you please have a look on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) and [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages).